# Am I Creepy - What am I?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

I come at night, and in the day.
I'm always there, do what you may.
You may think that I hate the light,
Because it is what gives you your sight.
But truthfully in light I trust,
Because for me it is a must.
Left or right, or down below
I'll follow you, fast or slow.
You really can't escape from me,
So tell me now, what I may be.

Comment: How did you pick (accept) one out of the three identical answers? _Fastest gun in the west_, is it?

Comment: When they were first posted, dmg had the answer with an explanation first. The second answer with an explanation came after I had accepted dmg already.

Comment: Timings - ditto - 15:29:16, dmg - 15:29:33, third identical answer - ages later (actually that's only 4 minutes, but relative to 17 seconds ...) Wow!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm guessing it's:

> darkness/shadow

Because:

I come at night, and in the day.

> The night is dark and there are shadows in the day.

I'm always there, do what you may.

> Your shadow is always there.

You may think that I hate the light,
Because it is what gives you your sight.
But truthfully in light I trust,
Because for me it is a must.

> There is no darkness or shadow without light. Also light "gives" us our sight. We need light to see.

Left or right, or down below

> Depending on light's position the shadow may fall in different directions.

I'll follow you, fast or slow.
You really can't escape from me,

> No matter how fast you move, your shadow is always there.

Comment: This is what I was answering. You beat me to it!

Comment: @IanMacDonald I took me while, cause I wanted to post the explanation as well. However, this does seem quite an easy riddle, so I might not be right.

Comment: Perfectly done. It was an easy one. I'll accept it when I can.

Comment: "Your shadow is always there." Not 100% true, there are conditions in which an object casts no discernible shadow.

Answer (score 6):

To me, this sounds like :

> a shadow ?

I come at night, and in the day.

> shadows are visible at both night and day (night they are dimmer, but even moon light will cast a shadow)

I'm always there, do what you may.

> Shadows are always there, just dimmer or such depending on the light.

You may think that I hate the light,
Because it is what gives you your sight.

> shadows are traditionally a lack of light  ..

But truthfully in light I trust,
Because for me it is a must.

> a shadow can't exist without light

Left or right, or down below
I'll follow you, fast or slow.
You really can't escape from me,

> no matter which way you move, turn, or fast/slow you go, your shadow will match you.

Comment: Hi Ditto, welcome to puzzling.SE. Could you add a reason to your answer please? If you don't explain what it is that makes you think that's the correct answer, then your answer runs the risk of being deleted.

Comment: @AE: ahh, ok .. first time posting, hadn't really noticed the convention :)

Answer (score 6):

i think it is

> your shadow

I come at night, and in the day.
I'm always there, do what you may.

> my shadow is always there, day or night

You may think that I hate the light,
Because it is what gives you your sight.

> light allows me to see the shadows following me when the light is bright

But truthfully in light I trust,
Because for me it is a must.

> I cant have shadow without a light, with a bright light, shadow is even more obvious

Left or right, or down below
I'll follow you, fast or slow.

> left or right depends on where the light source is. Or at noon, my shadow is directly under me

You really can't escape from me,
So tell me now, what I may be.

> cant separate me from my shadow

Answer (score 2):

I think it must be a shadow that follows one everywhere whether day or night and cannot be escaped. 
The line that says light is a must, and cannot be escaped.

Comment: Hi gjsldi12, welcome to puzzling.SE. We hope that you enjoy what you find here, and will join in the community.  

So that you know, general convention for answering riddles as such is to add an explanation to your answer as to why you think it fits. Also, it is considered good etiquette to not repeat an answer that has already been posted. You will notice on this particular question there were mutliple of the same answer, but that was due to almost simultaneous answering.

Comment: Just to add to Aggie's advice, there's also a convention of putting answers in spoilertags (use ">!") so that people have to mouse over to see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative answer that fits just like the original one:

> Air.

I come at night, and in the day.
I'm always there, do what you may.

> Air is always around us.

You may think that I hate the light,
Because it is what gives you your sight.

> Air distorts light, so one might think it dislikes light.

But truthfully in light I trust,
Because for me it is a must.

> Air as we know it is made by plants during the photosynthesis, which needs light.

Left or right, or down below
I'll follow you, fast or slow.
You really can't escape from me,

> Air is always around us, wherever we go. Even in space there is (very thin) air around us.

So tell me now, what I may be.